# Changing Fedora's builtin Hotspot mode to 5GHz

Tags: fedora, networkmanager, wifi-hotspot

I am using Fedora 22 and in the WiFi settings, I can enable a HotSpot. I found the `/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/Hotspot` file, but I do not know what I can do there.

I want the hotspot to use the 5GHz for testing purposes. How can I do that?

Comment: If you use NetworkManager on your Laptop follow this Tutorial on youtube that I just tested on openSUSE. On the Wi-Fi Tab you can select the Frequency (not shown in video). https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=auQ5tC1u6fM​